# Ms graph: get user by id

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get the user, who created and shared file.
To get user by id I call the endpoint `GET /users/{id}`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get

But instead file owner the endpoint returns current logged in user info.

I have two assumptions:

1. incorrect user id
2. incorrect permissions

**1. User id**. I got it from remoteItem.createdBy.user.id, where user is [Identity object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/identity.) and contains next properties:

```
{ displayName: '', id: '' }
```

There is a remark in the documentation:

> In some circumstances, the unique identifier for the actor may not be available. In this case, the displayName property for the identity will be returned, but the id property will be missing from the resource.

Well, maybe existing displayName means that id is incorrect? How to get owner user in this case?

**2. Permissions**. I've tried next permissions:

- Files.Read.All (Application/Delegated)
- User.Read.All (application/Delegated)

Any help is highly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: If you are using /users/me, it'll always return the current user. Or are you using another endpoint?

Comment: I'm using GET /users/{id}

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, when you want to get a specific user, you need to use `GET /users/{object-id | userPrincipalName}`, not `GET /me` which for the signed-in user, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{object-id | userPrincipalName}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 491

{
  "businessPhones": [
       "businessPhones-value"
   ],
   "displayName": "displayName-value",
   "givenName": "givenName-value",
   "jobTitle": "jobTitle-value",
   "mail": "mail-value",
   "mobilePhone": "mobilePhone-value",
   "officeLocation": "officeLocation-value",
   "preferredLanguage": "preferredLanguage-value",
   "surname": "surname-value",
   "userPrincipalName": "userPrincipalName-value",
   "id": "id-value"
}
```

Comment: Sure, I did GET request /users/{id} and logged in user is returned

Comment: @user34813 Did you use the object-id of the logged user? And how did you get the token to call the API?

Comment: @user34813 It is not related to the permissions, if you don’t have the permission, you will get 401 error. And your id should also be correct, so I think the user who you want to find is the logged user, it is just a coincidence.